# Inline-block for element

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I currently have a search "button" that I made sit on the side of a textbox, as shown in the picture below, this renders fine in chrome and firefox.

[image]

In IE9 it renders like this.

[image: IE Render]

Has anyone ran into a similar problem? How can I get around this?

The CSS for the search button is:

```
    .txtSearchBtn
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    top: 5px;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url(../Images/magnifier.png);
}
```

EDIT: The error seems to have something to do with my page being rendered inside of a fancybox. IE9 is not treating inline-block the same way outside of the fancybox.

EDIT 2: Figured out the problem. My max-width setting doesn't have enough room for the textbox and the image, even though I'm moving the image -20px to the left, so IE renders it on the line above.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with HTML/CSS/JS code that indicates issue you are facing?

Comment: When you figure out the reason is it good or bad practice to write it as an actual answer to your own question? Glad you found it though mate!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem due to IE being unable to recognize the attribute

```
display: inline-block;
```

IE explorer will display it inline, and to achieve the desired effect you need to give the content 'Layout' using

```
zoom: 1;
display: inline;
```

or similar.

This article was helpful to me, check it out to fully understand what I'm trying to say!

http://flipc.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html

EDIT: If you are ONLY trying to cover your back as far as IE9 and no less, then @Porco has that covered with the correct DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: well I know it's not displaying it inline, because it doesn't even show the button at all when I change it to display:inline; I'll take a look at the article you posted, thanks.

Comment: maybe add a bit of zoom on the outer div too. If in doubt put some zoom on it!!

Comment: no such luck.. I'm not looking to be any more backwards compatible then IE9. The problem seems to be related to this page being opened in a fancybox. When I just open the page in the browser it renders fine but opening it in a fancybox causes this weird shift

Answer (score 0):

IE support for inline-block got a lot better in IE8+. This sounds like you are rendering in compatiblity mode, which basically means render this page like you are IE7 (or worse - Quirks mode).

Are you declaring DOCTYPE? try adding this to the top of your html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

This should force it to use IE9 rendering which can do inline-block correctly.

Comment: I tried changing the DOCTYPE to the one you gave as I found that as a "solution" elsewhere. Didn't help. I'm not in compatibility mode I don't believe, I made sure it wasn't checked and I also have tried a different machine. Also I have CSS3 attributes elsewhere in my stylesheet which would have made things look REALLY weird.

Comment: In IE9 you should be able to hit F-12 to bring up Developer Toolbar. Check what Browser Mode and Document Mode it is rendering the page in?

Comment: Just realized this would probably help. This is inside of a fancybox. And I tried opening the page outside of a fancybox and it renders properly.

Comment: Ah, sounds complicated. I'm not really sure what you mean by fancybox but maybe you can reduce it down to something that can be reproduced on jsfiddle?

Comment: it's a jquery plugin. I actually figured out that my problem wasn't IE9 rendering the CSS wrong my width was too short.